# WPF Combox in DataGrid - SelectionChanged event returning selected ComboBoxItem as null

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

**Question**: Inside the `SelectionChanged` event of Combobox in `DataGrid`, the `ComboboxItem` is always null. What I may be missing and how we can fix the issue? Please note that (as shown in image 1) if you are able to select an item from the combobox, that means the combobox has already been loaded. And hence it's `SelectionChanged` event is called after combobox got loaded.

**Employee.cs**:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
```

**State.cs**:

```
public class State
{
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public string StateCode { get; set; }
}
```

**StateList.cs**:

```
public class StateList : List<State>
{
    public StateList()
    {
        Add(new State { StateName = "Iowa", StateCode = "IA" });
        Add(new State { StateName = "Nebraska", StateCode = "NE" });
        Add(new State { StateName = "Ohio", StateCode = "OH" });
        Add(new State { StateName = "Virginia", StateCode = "VA" });
    }
}
```

**Combobox SelectionChanged event** [**always** returns cmbItem as null]:

```
private void cmbState_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    StateList states = new StateList();
    string st = "";
    ComboBoxItem cmbItem = ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem);
    if(cmbItem != null)
        st = "   You selected " + cmbItem.Content.ToString() + ".";
}
```

**Snapshot of changing the selection**:

[image]

**ComboboxItem showing as null**:

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_DataGridCombobox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        .......
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:StateList x:Key="ListOfStates"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgEmplyees" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Update">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Click="btnUpdate_Click"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding  Name}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="State Name">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StateName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbState" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ListOfStates}" DisplayMemberPath="StateName" SelectedValuePath="StateName" SelectedValue="{Binding StateName}" SelectionChanged="cmbState_SelectionChanged" IsEditable="False" IsReadOnly="True" />                            
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: `(sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem` is null because SelectedItem is not a ComboBoxItem. It is a State object.

Comment: @Clemens I'm following the example of  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1) official document from Microsoft team. Am I misunderstanding the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem
```

is `null` because SelectedItem is not a ComboBoxItem. It would be a ComboBoxItem if you had explicitly added ComboBoxItems, e.g. like

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBox>
```

Since you have assiged a collection of State objects to the ItemsSource property of the ComboBox, SelectedItem is a State object:

```
private void cmbState_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var state = (State)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment, so I write it here.
In the example from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1) they add objects of type `ListBoxItem` to the ListBox. Therefore `SelectedItem` can be parsed as `ListBoxItem` here.
But you use the list `ListOfStates`, so the `SelectedItem` is of type `State`.  Therefore you must write: `State state = ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as State);`

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow`. Thank your for sharing your knowledge. It was helpful.